# C++ how to restart the loop if user just presses enter or if the input is invalid?

Tags: c++, validation, vector

I'll start by saying I have worked on this for 3 days now and this is only my second semester programming. I know this question is probably easy for most, but I really have very little experience.

The code I have written all works as intended except the invalid/blank entry validation. Anything I have found and tried just breaks other parts of the code or doesn't work at all.

Here are the instructions given in the homework for the part I am having issues with:
"**Any invalid input for the menu will simply redisplay the menu.
Option 1 will prompt for a userName. An empty name will be ignored.**"

Here is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>



using namespace std;
vector<string> usernames;
void listMenu();
void addName();
void listNames();
void removeName();

int main()
{

    char entry;
    bool exit = false;

    while (exit == false)
    {

        cout << "Choose from the following menu: \n";
        listMenu();
        cin >> entry;

        if (entry == '\n')
        {
            listNames();
        }

        if (entry == '1')
        {
            addName();
        }
        else if (entry == '2')
        {
            listNames();
        }
        else if (entry == '3')
        {
            removeName();
        }
        else if (entry == 'x' || entry == 'X')
        {
            exit = true;
        }



    } 



    usernames.clear();
    return 0;

}

void listMenu()
{
    string menu[4] = { "1. Add a username","2. List all usernames","3. Delete a username","X. Exit" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            cout << menu[i] << endl;
        }

}

void addName()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter a username: " << endl;
    cin >> name;    
    usernames.push_back(name);

}

void listNames()
{
    int n = 1;
    cout << "**************\n";
    for (auto& x : usernames)
    {
        cout << n <<". "<< x <<endl;
        n++;
    }
    cout << "**************\n";
}

void removeName()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Which username would you like to remove?\n";
    listNames;
    cin >> x;

    usernames.erase(usernames.begin()+x);
}
```

Comment: Do some research: this question has been answered often (although the answer just posted is an example of a wrong one).

Comment: I have certainly searched far and wide for an answer and have tried numerous iterations, including those similar to the one below, and all have failed. That is why i am posting here. I am simply at the end of my rope and frustrated.

Comment: When doing formatted reads, you won't get a spaces as by default leading whitespace is skipped (look for `std::noskipws`). Also, you **always** want to check whether reading was successful **after** an attempt to read. Both of these issues have been commented on many times.

Comment: Thanks! I was finally able to get it to work my changing my input to getline () and using usernames.empty ()

Answer (score 0):

You can test your input and clear it if it's invalid. Using `cin.fail`, `cin.clear` and `cin.ignore`.

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  

bool cond;  

int main() {  
    int n;  

    do {  
        cout << "Enter an integer number:";  
        cin >> n;  

        cond = cin.fail();  

        cin.clear();  
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');  
    } while(cond);  

    return 0;  
}
```